# Checking if username exists in MySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a register dialog that implements an action listener. If a user enters a name and it already exists, I want to print a message on the console. If the username does not exist, MySQL should add it into the database. Unfortunately this code won't work:

```
private void regButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(!userBox.getText().equals(""))
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/genx", "root", "Warlock1989");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT name FROM accounts";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String uname = rs.getString("name");
                if(!uname.equals(userBox.getText()))
                {
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO accounts(name) VALUES(?)");
                    pstmt.setString(1, userBox.getText());
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Username " + userBox.getText() + " has been registered.");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Username " + userBox.getText() + " already exists.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean?

Comment: print your stack trace

Comment: There's no stack trace. Nothing happens at all. It doesn't call if, else or catch.

Comment: Is your table empty? Because then the select will return no rows, and `rs.next()` will return `false`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach loads all records from database and tries to find the user which will cause memory exceptions if the database consists of huge records. So,
**Do not fetch all records from database** rather simply run the query using `where name=?` to check user already exists in the database as shown below:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {

    String userInput = userBox.getText();

    String query = "SELECT name FROM accounts where name=?";
    pstmt1 = con.preparedStatement(query);
    pstmt1.setString(1, userInput);

    rs = pstmt1.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()) {
            pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO accounts(name) VALUES(?)");
            pstmt2.setString(1, userInput);
            pstmt2.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Username " + userInput + " has been registered.");
    }  else {
            System.out.println("Username " + userInput + " already exists.");
    }

} catch(SQLException sqlexe) {
    //add logging
} finally {
    if(pstmt1 != null)
       pstmt1.close();
    if(pstmt2 != null)
       pstmt2.close();
     if(rs != null)
       rs.close();
}
```

Your current code does not release the `resultsset` & `preparedstatement` objects, so ensure that you are releasing the resources in the finally block.